# async/await issue with dialog box (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, async-await, modal-dialog

I'm not a professional. I cannot get the solution with the code below. The console.log() statements are OK, the call to showNameDialogBox is OK, and the dialog box appears with the (dummy) information passed as arguments... but, the Promise doesn't work at all and, of course, the dialog box doesn't close — obviously something I didn't do correctly.

Thanks in advance for your input.

```
const showNameDialogBox = async (firstName, fullname, gender, country) => { // Always returns a promise
  initNameDialog(firstName, fullname, gender, country)
  nameManagementDialog.showModal()

  await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

    // The executor is an anonymous function that is executed automatically after the Promise is constructed
    // (the two parameters are defined internally in JS, nothing to do here)

    document.getElementById("nameAddButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
      addNameToBase()
      resolve("Added")    // Calls resolve to issue "Added" as a fulfilled value for the Promise
    })

    document.getElementById("nameSkipButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
      resolve("Skipped")  // Calls resolve to issue "Skipped" as a fulfilled value for the Promise
    })
  }) // End of new Promise (constructor)

  nameManagementDialog.close()

} // End of showNameDialogBox

      console.log("Before showNameDialog");
      (async function () {
        await showNameDialogBox("Zorro", "Cavalier nommé Zorro", "Male", "California, United States");  // Test
        let nameSelected = document.getElementById("name").value.toLowerCase();
        nameSelected = nameSelected.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + nameSelected.slice(1);
        console.log(nameSelected);
      })()
      console.log("After showNameDialog");
```

Comment: Insert a `console.log("whatever");` just before `nameManagementDialog.close()` and see if it logs once you click either one of the buttons.

Comment: Nothing is printed

Comment: Even when you click to `nameSkipButton`? Then you have to check modal. Also `showNameDialogBox` is an async function and you are expected to return a promise finally so that you `await showNameDialogBox("Zorro", "Don Diego", "Male", "California, United States");` before `console.log('After await');`.

Answer (score 1):

It is just not how you use Promises. Just kick it out and have your event listeners trigger the `close()` action directly:

```
const showNameDialogBox = (firstName, fullname, gender, country) => {

  initNameDialog(firstName, fullname, gender, country)
  nameManagementDialog.showModal()

  document.getElementById("nameAddButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    addNameToBase()
    nameManagementDialog.close()
  })

  document.getElementById("nameSkipButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    nameManagementDialog.close()
  })

}

console.log('Before await');
showNameDialogBox("Zorro", "Don Diego", "Male", "California, United States");
console.log('After await');
```

(Note that `close()` should probably also remove the event listeners)

Though in general, your code should work too, but you need to await `showNameDialogBox()` if you want to wait between the `console.log()` statements:

```
console.log('Before await');
await showNameDialogBox("Zorro", "Don Diego", "Male", "California, United States");
console.log('After await');
```

You might want to check though if it isn't easier to change to an event-driven approach, where one event (i.e. closing the name modal) triggers another event (i.e. opening the next dialog), instead of having a fixed flow that waits for a set of fixed steps. The advantage is that you can easily go back and forth between those loosely coupled steps. Then again, if it works for you, it works.

---

You say in the comments that you are still struggling, maybe this example can help:

```js
const setClickHandler = (id, callback) => {
  const el = document.getElementById(id)
  const onClickHandler = () => {
    el.disabled = true
    el.removeEventListener('click', onClickHandler)
    callback(id)
  }
  el.disabled = false
  el.addEventListener('click', onClickHandler)
}


const deferClick = async(res = []) => {
  const id = 1 + Math.random() * 3 | 0
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const onClickHandler = () => {
      res.push(id)
      const keepGoing = Math.random() < 1.0 / res.length
      resolve(keepGoing ? deferClick(res) : res)
    }
    setClickHandler('b' + id, onClickHandler)
  })
}

(async() => {
  const res = await deferClick()
  console.log('Done, clicked numbers were ' + JSON.stringify(res))
})()
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="b1" disabled>1</button>
  <button id="b2" disabled>2</button>
  <button id="b3" disabled>3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Moritz. This simpler code shows the modal BUT the program doesn't stop and wait for the user to click either the "Skip" or "Add" buttons... That's why I thought of using async/await and promises. Afterward, a dialog of another type is opened and the program crashes.

Comment: @user8889350 Ah, interesting, then I understand what was missing before. I updated my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, it is. Now it works BUT the program did not stop while the dialog was opened.  I edited the code in my post. Here is what the debugger says...

```Before showNameDialog
After showNameDialog
Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: searchPerson is not defined
    at createTree (----.html:691:52)
    at launchPgm (----.html:454:11)
    --- await ---
    at onclick (----.html:121:53)
Whatever name   // I typed this string in the dialog```

Comment: The function searchPerson is called far away below in the code. The uncaught error was expected since I did not write it up there.

I expected that "Whatever name" appeared before the Uncaught Error message, proving the dialog really expected for the click on the "Add" button.

Comment: @user8889350 Oh, I see, remove the IIFE (`(async function(){...})()`), or you'll have the same problem as before. If you get an error because you cannot await on top level, add them again but put the whole script into it. Shouldn't have started with it without knowing if that is even an issue. Sorry.

Comment: Still lost. Here is the debugger's output with some additional `console.log`.

Before showNameDialog
Before (async function () {
Inside showNameDialog
After (async function () { // The promise seemed to be fulfilled, but not in fact
Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: searchPerson is not defined
    at createTree    // Obviously, the JS did not stop and await for a clickButton event
    at launchPgm
    --- await ---
    at onclick
Name Dialog just closed // Here, I clicked on "Add" button after changing the name
Taratata
{name: 'Taratata', sex: '', given: false, family: true}